# Select only date and related row based on condition from a long format file

Tags: r, bash, text-processing

I have a csv file, which can be imported into R. 
It is a dataframe with many columns in the "long form", i.e. there are multiple entries for the same ID. I am reproducing an example of the dataset and the resulting dataset I am trying to obtain, using only the first 5 columns (I actually have a lot more columns in my real data). The original dataset can be reproduced in R with this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("id1","id1","id2","id2","id2","id2","id3","id3"), date = c("30/10/20010 from Steve.","30/16/2005 from Anna. 09/08/2008 from Steve. 09/10/2009 from Steve.","06/05/2004 from Allen.","08/09/2005 from Anna.","08/05/2008 from Allen. 30/10/2010 from Bobby.","14/03/2002 from Steve. 23/07/2003 from Anna.","08/08/2002 from Steve.", "08/08/2002 from Anna. 08/08/2002 from Steve."), v1 = c(1,NA,1,1,2,NA,1,2), v2 = c(2,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,2,NA), v3 = c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,1,1,NA), v4 = c("Y","N","N","Y","NA","NA","Y","Y"), v5 = c(0,0,NA,0,0,NA,0,NA))
```

> id                                                                date   v1 v2   v3 v4 v5
>
> 1 id1                                             30/10/20010 from Steve.    1  2   1   Y   0
>
> 2 id1 30/16/2005 from Anna. 09/08/2008 from Steve. 09/10/2009 from Steve.   NA NA   NA  N   0
>
> 3 id2                                              06/05/2004 from Allen.    1  2   NA  N   NA
>
> 4 id2                                               08/09/2005 from Anna.    1 NA   2   Y   0
>
> 5 id2                       08/05/2008 from Allen. 30/10/2010 from Bobby.    2 NA   NA  NA  0
>
> 6 id2                        14/03/2002 from Steve. 23/07/2003 from Anna.   NA NA   1   NA  NA
>
> 7 id3                                              08/08/2002 from Steve.    1  2   1   Y   0
>
> 8 id3                        08/08/2002 from Anna. 08/08/2002 from Steve.    2 NA   NA  Y   NA

What I am trying to get is a dataset selecting only the row with the latest date from the column `date` for each id, and if the dates are all the same, select the row with the least number of NAs (of missing values):

> id                                                    date   v1 v2   v3 v4 v5
>
> 1 id1                                             30/10/20010    1  2   1   Y   0
>
> 5 id2                                              30/10/2010    2 NA   NA  NA  0
>
> 7 id3                                              08/08/2002    1  2   1   Y   0

I thought of splitting the columns in R using "from" as a separator, but this doesn't really take me anywhere:

```
try<- strsplit(df$date, "from", fixed=TRUE)
```

Then I thought that it may be better to select the dates in BASH: but this also does not take me anywhere:

```
grep "[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/20[0-9][0-9]" file.csv | less -S
```

Basically, I am lost in how to approach this. 
I would be VERY grateful if someone could please suggest the correct approach, hopefully just using BASH or R? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script that works on your example data

(after correcting two dates: `30/10/20010 --> 30/10/2010` and `30/16/2005 --> 30/06/2005`)

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("id1","id1","id2","id2","id2","id2","id3","id3"), date = c("30/10/2010 from Steve.","30/06/2005 from Anna. 09/08/2008 from Steve. 09/10/2009 from Steve.","06/05/2004 from Allen.","08/09/2005 from Anna.","08/05/2008 from Allen. 30/10/2010 from Bobby.","14/03/2002 from Steve. 23/07/2003 from Anna.","08/08/2002 from Steve.", "08/08/2002 from Anna. 08/08/2002 from Steve."), v1 = c(1,NA,1,1,2,NA,1,2), v2 = c(2,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,2,NA), v3 = c(1,NA,NA,2,NA,1,1,NA), v4 = c("Y","N","N","Y","NA","NA","Y","Y"), v5 = c(0,0,NA,0,0,NA,0,NA))

# Convert string to list of dates, extract maximum (earliest date)
df.dates <- sapply(as.character(df$date), function(x) strsplit(x, "\\."))
df.dates <- lapply(df.dates, function(x) as.Date(x, format='%d/%m/%Y'))
df.dates <- lapply(df.dates, max)

# Add to dataframe
df$latest <- unlist(df.dates)

# Count the number of NA values per row
df$naCount <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x[3:7])))

# Split data and select either maximum (latest) date or minimal NA count
df.split <- split(df, df$id)

df.select <- lapply(df.split, function(x){

    # Select by given criterion
    if(length(unique(x$latest)) == 1){
        y <- x[which(min(x$naCount) == x$naCount),]
        }
    else{
        y <- x[which(max(x$latest) == x$latest),]
    }

    # Check if selection was successful
    if(nrow(y) != 1) cat('Warning: non-unique choice, returning more than one line')

    # Return result
    y
})

# Combine into output dataframe
df.select <- do.call(rbind, df.select)
```

The result of the script looks like this:

```
> df.select

     id                                          date v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 latest naCount
id1 id1                        30/10/2010 from Steve.  1  2  1  Y  0  14912       0
id2 id2 08/05/2008 from Allen. 30/10/2010 from Bobby.  2 NA NA NA  0  14912       2
id3 id3                        08/08/2002 from Steve.  1  2  1  Y  0  11907       0
```

Comment: Dear yellowcap, thank you very much for your help, the code works, only some warnings after this step: "df.dates <- lapply(df.dates, max)" saying "In max.default(structure(numeric(0), class = "Date"),  ... : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf",   but I am guessing there are probably problems in my original dataset. What you did is very smart and I don't think I could have got to it for now on my own, so I really have to study your code carefully now. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Hi again, I have just re-checked this and it is giving me many errors, the problem is when I have not unique dates as well as duplicates within the same ID, so for example if I add a fourth id like this:

Comment: df <- data.frame(id = c("id4", "id4", "id4"), date = c("06/08/2002 from Julian.", "08/08/2002 from Kate.", "08/08/2002 by Carrie. 08/08/2002 from Kate."), v1 = c(NA, 3, NA), v2 = c(NA,2,NA), v3 = c(NA,1,NA), v4 = c("N", "Y", "N"), v5 = c(0,0,0))